# gimp - how to round corners of shapes

Tags: gimp

How to round corners of shapes in Gimp?
like this:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try combination of `Select -> Shrink` and then `Select -> Grow` with same offset value. This should result in selection with rounded corners.

Doing a `Select -> Invert` afterwards will give you what you want to delete ...

Comment: it works. So nice.

Answer (score 5):

I would do it by `select->Rounded Rectangle` while adjusting `radius` then `invert` and `delete` or `feather` depending on required corner shape